# Googleスプレッドシートでコメントを一括削除する方法

Tags: google-apps-script

Googleスプレッドシートで、シート内のコメントをすべて一括削除する方法はあるでしょうか。
（検索してもセルごとに削除する方法しか出てきません。）

Comment: `検索してもセルごとに削除する方法しか出てきません。`について、セルごとに削除する方法しかない理由は理解できませんが、もしもご質問にあるコメントが、メモではないコメントの削除であれば、Drive APIのComments: deleteメソッドを使用するのはいかがでしょうか。 [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/delete) "一括削除"をしたい場合は、バッチリクエストを使うと、非同期で実行されるため、コストを低くすることは可能かと思われます。OPの状況が正しく理解できたかどうか不明なため、コメントでの提案です。